# Remove 'low' label for Highcharts Range chart

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I have a range chart that I need to remove the 'low' labels from (but keep the 'high' labels).

http://jsfiddle.net/CJQmL/

I could 'hack' this and just set `xLow: -9999999` (as commented out in the jsfiddle), but there has to be a way to remove the label through the custom formatter, right?  For my formatter I have (Note: this is not working - it's displaying both labels still. I need to fix this somehow to not display the Low label):

```
formatter: function () {
    if (this.point.high) {
        var myDate = new Date(this.y);
        var newDateMs = Date.UTC(myDate.getUTCFullYear(), myDate.getUTCMonth(), myDate.getUTCDate() + 1);
        return '<b>' + Highcharts.dateFormat('%m/%e', newDateMs) + '</b>';
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Basically, I'm just not sure what to put as the condition in place of `this.point.high`.  I want to be be:

```
if (point is high) {
    return date;
} else {
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Your solutions are fine, and indeed formatter makes sense ;)

Comment: My formatter isn't doing what I want it to, though.  The only way I can get it to work so far is by using the `xLow` setting, but I feel like there's a cleaner way of accomplishing this by using the formatter.

Comment: Indeed, my bad, you can use also additional solution, which iterate on each element, and remove datalabel http://jsfiddle.net/CJQmL/2/

Comment: Awesome, that's more what I was looking for.  Feel free to post that as answer so I can mark it as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use also additional solution, which iterate on each element, and remove datalabel

```
$.each(chart.series[0].data,function(i,e){
        e.dataLabel.destroy();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CJQmL/2/

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar issue where I had to display difference between high and low values in column range highcharts. The solution is:

```
var test = [];
var plotOptions =  {
    formatter: function() {
    if(test.indexOf(this.point.index) == -1) {
        test.push(this.point.index)
        return '<div style="text-align:center;">' + formatTimeText(this.point.options.high - this.point.options.low)+'</div>';
}
    else
        return null;
   }
}
```

While adding data labels to the graph, highcharts first prepares data labels for low values and then the high values. But the advantage is it maintains an index for every pair of (high,low) values.
So, if condition checks whether the index already exists, if it does not it returns the data label for the column. But if it exists then it will just return null. So the result is it will display either high data label or low data label